# VS code is showing me +5000 files that supposedly have changed on my "macbook" repository, i don't know how this happened

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code, github-desktop

This is why i think it has created a git repo on my main drive:

[image]

Not sure how this happened:

[image]

I think, I mistakenly added my macbook drive as a repository from Github desktop and i don't know how to get rid of this.

Comment: Here's a fun read related to this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32405

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fixed itself, I don't really know what happened here but thanks for the support.

Comment: Me too, I just reload the Windows and it is fixed. It's not because of the `.git` directory in the home folder.

Answer (score 10):

All of those folders look like they're in your home folder (`~`, which is the same as `/Users/GabrielCereal`). See if you have a `.git` folder in your home folder (`~/.git`). If so, delete it.

If you do have a Git repository at `~/.git`, you created it by running `git init` in your home dir (`~`), or by doing the equivalent in VS Code. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer from Mkasberg.

You can navigate to the folder. and press Cmd + shift + .

This will allow you to see in finder the hidden folder such as .git